# Specify only one jump direction of LocatorPane

Tags: dynamic

Considering `LocatorPane`:

```
LocatorPane[pts,back,{{xmin,ymin},{xmax,ymax},{dx,dy}}]
```

Is there any way to specify only the jumps `dx` and `dy` in `LocatorPane` and keep the `x` any `y` ranges automatic?
If that cannot be then is there any way to specify the `x` range and `dx` jump only?
I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
LocatorPane[{1, 1}/2, 
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
  ImageSize -> 400], {{0, Automatic}, {10, Automatic}, {1,Automatic}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {1, 1}/2}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, pt = Round[#, 1]; &],
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 400]]]
```

Comment: Solves my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 400];
{dx, dy} = {1, 1};
loc = Append[Transpose[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[p, PlotRange]], {dx, dy}]; 
LocatorPane[{1, 1}/2, p, loc]
```

Comment: +1, Thanks but the `back` is little complicated that finding the range using `AbsoluteOptions`

Comment: @Algohi I don't get you ...

Comment: I have a complex dynamic interaction code contains several nested `DynamicModules` and the result is a dynamic interaction Plot. finding range using `AbsoluteOptions` means running the code (in best cases) twice to get the range which means time consuming. Any way thanks.